# How to assign a variable to information contained in a link? (Javascript/HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, variables, hyperlink

I'm a beginner programmer, and I have a question about assigning a variable to information in a link. I can't give the exact example, so I'll try to come up with something that will show you what I mean:

Imagine there is a bunch of links in which all that is written is:

{"first_name": John, "last_name": Doe, "age": 37};

Another link would contain:

{"first_name": Jona, "last_name": Dona, "age": 71};

Nothing else. I can't control the links, but I need to assign such objects to some variable so I can use these attributes in some functions of mine later on.

(For example (first link):    var x=information_in_first_link;    < here, x."age" would be 37.)

Is that at all possible? How can I go about it?

Thanks in advance! :)

(Edited to make clearer...)

Comment: "a bunch of links in which all that is written is" — Off the top of my head, I can think of three different interpretations of that statement with significantly different meanings. Try a practical example of actual code. Try making a start to solving the problem.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear actually. How would your html look in your example? And what data (variable) do you want to get out of the link? (Example: <a href="http://google.com">{"first_name": John, "last_name": Doe, "age": 37}</a> I want to extract the first name from this.)

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear!
What I meant was, there is a site that is not mine, which contains such information. (the one I put between brackets.) I need, for example, to use the age and do some maths with it. So I need a variable like this:
var example={"first_name": John, "last_name": Doe, "age": 37};
that would help me get the age by doing example."age" or something. Is that clearer?

Comment: @Rita — It sounds like you are looking for an introductory ajax tutorial and information about bypassing the same origin policy. That's a really broad topic and not really suitable for a stackoverflow question.

Comment: I don't know how to put that link and use it. Is it between <script></script> tags or? and how would I manage to get the variable to contain the information inside the link?

Comment: @Quentin Yeah... I probably do need a tutorial since I've never heard of Ajax lol. I hope someone will manage to find a simple solution, and if not, I suppose it's all right :)

Comment: @Rita — There isn't a simple solution. You're talking about fetching data form another website, which you'll need a server side intermediary for since security policies prevent you from making your visitor's browsers fetch data from other websites directly, extracting specific data from it, parsing it into a JavaScript data structure, and then getting the data from it. It isn't *difficult*, but there are quite a lot of pieces that you need to deal with.

Comment: Seriously, go and find an introductory Ajax tutorial. Learn the basics. See what problems you run into. See what error messages you get. Then ask questions. This is too broad a problem for SO at present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone's interested, I found my answer here: http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_http.asp

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "myurl";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var example = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        myFunction(example);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(arr) {...}
```

I learned that the format I was talking about was called JSON. You can learn more about it in the link I posted in the beginning of the post. :)